# How to enable apt upgrade after removing PackageKit

Tags: apt, upgrade, kde

Recently I wanted to try out KDE with Ubuntu. Unfortunatly I didn't know it could easily be done with kubuntu-desktop so I mannually added the KDE Neon PPA and found that was a big mistake. Long story short, much crashing and bugs in the UI ensued so I tried my best to remove all traces and reinstall the original 18.04 desktop with the ubuntu-desktop. I was able to install that without a hitch and everything is working just fine again other than one little pain, apt upgrade.

KDE comes with PackageKit and it disables apt upgrade entirely so that you only get this little gem

```
On KDE neon you should use "pkcon update" to install updates.
If you absolutely must use apt you do have to use dist-upgrade or full-upgrade in place of the upgrade command.
```

I've tried uninstalling PackageKit but I still get this message every time I attempt to use apt upgrade. I've tried searching up a fix but with no luck. I've even attempted to reinstall apt itself (using apt) but still get the same message. Yes, I can use apt dist-upgrade but I'd rather not.

Comment: `packagekit` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/kubuntu-desktop) is recommended for `kubuntu-desktop` too, I suspect the issue is KDE neon packages are higher (to replace Kubuntu ones) thus if you'll likely still have neon packages creating your problems (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/packagekit or 1.1.9-1ubuntu2 is Ubuntu bionic package; what's yours? `apt-cache policy`).   In your situation I'd be tempted to re-install (using 'something-else' & no-format of partitions so data isn't touched, added packages get re-installed automatically, but backup first anyway!) as it'll be less work.

Comment: Tempted but leaving that as a last resort. If there were more issues still lurking around then most definetly but I think I've got most of KDE removed. This seems to be the only reminance that I can tell.

Comment: I don't know how neon packages will impact `ubuntu-support-status`, but that may provide a clue as to what % of your packages are unsupported (I'm guessing neon should show as unsupported esp. if neon sources are removed; maybe using `--show-unsupported` will provide a glimpse of what's left...)

Comment: By the way, *packagekit* is part of Ubuntu as well!

Comment: Looking at ubuntu-support-status, it looks like most unsupported packages are ones I have installed such as graphics drivers. The only KDE packages are qml-modules. Most of KDE has been removed, I even uninstalled packagekit, the package responsible for pkcon, however with still no luck. It seems to have changed a configuration somewhere.

Comment: I second what @guiverc suggested. Backup your data and do a clean re-install of whichever distro you like. I prefer not to have more than one desktop environment on my work machine. But that's your call.